# How to implement row level security in ASP.NET boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate, row-level-security

I started using ASP.NET Boilerplate a month back, so this is a beginner-level question. I feel it's a great framework — thanks a lot for creating and sharing this.

I was developing a multi-tenant application and now I want to filter rows based on tenant. What is the correct way of doing it in ASP.NET Boilerplate? I was thinking of passing `TenantId` with every DB call or creating a request context, which would have all details, and passing that along to the method call. And then, in the method, check if that particular row's `TenantId` matches with what we are passing. If not then discard, else proceed. With a few tweaks here and there, I may achieve what I want, but I want to know what is the correct way of doing it in ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Second, any out-of-the-box example of integrating Row Level Security feature of SQL Server in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. Could you just paste the code along with the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was developing a multi-tenant application and now I want to filter rows based on tenant. What is the correct way of doing it in ASP.NET Boilerplate? I was thinking of passing `TenantId` with every DB call or creating a request context, which would have all details, and passing that along to the method call. And then, in the method, check if that particular row's `TenantId` matches with what we are passing. If not then discard, else proceed.

That's a built-in feature of ASP.NET Boilerplate, implemented via EF Core's [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

More info: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#data-filters

> Second, any out-of-the-box example of integrating Row Level Security feature of SQL Server in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

No, all DB calls are made by the same trusted DB user determined by the connection string.

You might have misunderstood [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017).

You could pass a different connection string based on the application user, but that's simply application-level authorization — also built-in, implemented via Castle Windsor's [Interceptors](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md).

More info: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#data-filters  ideally explains the filter with TenantId and with IPermissionChecker (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization ) I can achieve what I want.Thanks a lot for sharing these details.